# MenuControl in asp.net from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a menu control in my Master page.T he name of the menu and corresponding url is coming from the database. If a menu has a sub menu it is also showing properly.
But the problem arises if a sub menu has a child menu.
My database table has 4 columns
MenuId || MenuName || ParentId || URL.

and the code is

```
 private void getMenu()
 {
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     ds = objSec.ShowMenu(s_UserId);

     dt = ds.Tables[0];
     DataRow[] drowpar = dt.Select("ParentID=" + 0);

     foreach (DataRow dr in drowpar)
     {
         menuBar.Items.Add(new MenuItem(dr["MenuName"].ToString(), dr["MenuID"].ToString(),
         "", dr["URL"].ToString()));
     }

     foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select("ParentID >" + 0))
     {
         try
         {
             MenuItem mnu = new MenuItem(dr["MenuName"].ToString(), dr["MenuID"].ToString(),
              "", dr["URL"].ToString());
              menuBar.FindItem(dr["ParentID"].ToString()).ChildItems.Add(mnu);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {                  
         }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach in your sample might lead to incorrect results if sub-items are contained in the table before their parent-item. In addition, the empty catch-block might hide any errors. Therefore, I'd recommend another approach.

Instead of looping the table, you can also use recursion to fill the control. This removes the amount of duplicated code:

```
private void getMenu()
{
    DataSet ds = objSec.ShowMenu(s_UserId);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    AddMenuItems(dt, 0, menu.Items);
}

private void AddMenuItems(DataTable dt, int parentId, MenuItemCollection items)
{
    DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("ParentID=" + parentId.ToString());
    foreach(var dr in rows)
    {
        var id = (int) dr["MenuID"];
        var menuItem = new MenuItem(dr["MenuName"].ToString(), id.ToString(),
                                    "", dr["URL"].ToString());
        items.Add(menuItem);
        // Add subitems
        AddMenuItems(dt, id, menuItem.ChildItems); 
    }
}
```

The sample first calls the AddMenuItems method for the top-level items (ParentID = 0). After each item is added, its children are added by calling the AddMenuItems method again (hence the term "recursive"), providing the id of the top-level item as parent. For each 2nd level child, the method is called again and so on.